# multiline regex pattern for text patterns

Tags: python, regex

I hav 100s of pages of the following type transcript:

```
<p><strong>ROGELIO JIMÉNEZ PONS:</strong> Quisiera
<p>Text here...</p>
<p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:</strong>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p><strong>PREGUNTA:</strong>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:</strong>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p><strong>INTERLOCUTOR:</strong>
```

I want to capture and return just what the Obrador says:

```
<p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:</strong>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p>Text here...</p>

<p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:</strong>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
```

I get close with this regex:

```
<p><strong>PRESIDENTE(.*)\n(.*)?\n?(.*)?\n?(.*)
```

But not quite right since I can't seem to work out the end of the pattern which should end with

```
<p><strong>[ANYTHING NOT PRESIDENTE]
```

Comment: you want to get the text after Obrador ?

Comment: Please explain if `PRESIDENTE` or `OBRADOR` is stable words ? also you would like to just get the `text` of what `Obrador` Says ?

Comment: I need anything between <p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:</strong> AND <p><strong>[anything else]

Comment: check my answer ! if it's not so please edit your question with input and output example ! as i couldn't understand you clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OBRADOR:<\/strong>\r?\n((?:(?!<p><strong>)^[^\r\n]+\r?\n)+)
```