# Python script with regex returns empty list

Tags: python, regex

This is a follow up to a question about [multiline regex pattern for text patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58896204/multiline-regex-pattern-for-text-patterns?noredirect=1#comment104057460_58896204) but I need it to work as part of a python script.

This regex patter:

```
<p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:<\/strong>\r?\n((?:(?!<p><strong>)^[^\r\n]+\r?\n)+)
```

works to find all text by Obrador in hundreds of pages as in this example:

```
<p><strong>ROGELIO JIMÉNEZ PONS:</strong> Quisiera</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:</strong>Some words here.</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p><strong>PREGUNTA:</strong>Some question here.</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:</strong>Some words here.</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p>Text here...</p>
<p><strong>INTERLOCUTOR:</strong>
```

You can see [test here](https://regex101.com/r/CgQCvJ/3)

But when I put it into the following python script, it returns an empty list:

```
regex_match = re.compile(r'<p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:<\/strong>\r?\n((?:(?!<p><strong>)^[^\r\n]+\r?\n)+)', re.MULTILINE)
text_obrador = regex_match.findall(str(all_text))
print(text_obrador)
```

Just to test it, I tried the following, and it returned just the first p tag content:

```
regex_match = re.compile(r'<p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:<\/strong>\r?.+', re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Please learn about the Beautiful Soup library.

Comment: I’ve scraped using BeautifulSoup. But there are no tags to distinguish the president from other speakers. Unless I’m missing something. There are no children below the president strong tags. Tim, Can you be more specific about which aspect of BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Agree with @TimBiegeleisen. Regex are not the proper way to parse HTML. I suggest you to combine `BeautifulSoup` (great for stateful connection) and `lxml` (to allow the use of XPath). I've a repo on this, it may offer a sample: https://github.com/gsscoder/facebook-snooper/.

Comment: Your tags look unbalanced.  Where do the `<p>` tags for the president text get closed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, you're right. fixing that now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the script now works beautifully. When i created the example, i didn't close the p tags. Added the p tags to the regex, it now cycles through the thousands of pages and returns just the president's text. Thanks for catching that.BTW, i used BeautifulSoup to scrape hundreds of webpages with the speeches, got just the div on each page i needed and now used regex to focus on the president's text.

Comment: @SMJune I would be quite surprised if it were impossible to find a tag based on its text content in BeautifulSoup.

Comment: To explain better: `regex` are not the proper way to parse **HTML** but are wonderful if you need to need to extract something with a vell defined pattern. I used it to steal data from **JavaScript** code inside `<script>...</script>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the missing closing p tags as pointed about by @TimBiegeleisen and added that to regex. Now when i run:

```
regex_match = re.compile(r'<p><strong>PRESIDENTE ANDRÉS MANUEL LÓPEZ OBRADOR:<\/strong>.+\r?\n((?:(?!<p><strong>)^[^\r\n]+\r?\n)+)', re.MULTILINE)
text_obrador = regex_match.findall(str(all_text))
print(text_obrador)
```

In the actual text, it works.